# hold continuous number in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I store an order number in a mysql db. My php script reads the value and adds 1 to the number.

Now I use this number in several shops so many programs read and update the value.

Today I have the problem, that two scripts read the same time and got the same value.

So two different orders from two different shops got the same number ????

In the log-files I see that the two orders where placed the same time.

```
$sqls  = "Select value from db_config ";
$sqls .= "WHERE name = 'ordernumber' FOR UPDATE";
$rs = $db->query($sqls);
while($rows=$db->fetch($rs))
{
    $_CONF['aufnr'] = $rows['value'];
}
$sqlu  = "Update db_config ";
$sqlu .= "SET value=value+1 ";
$sqlu .= "WHERE name = 'ordernumber' ";
$ru = $db->query($sqlu);
```

How can I prevent this ?
For my ERP-System it is neccessary to have one continous Number.

And I don't want to lock the table, because of an error that lets the table locked !

I hope, somebody has an idea
bye jogi

Comment: Why would you need continuous numbers if the numbers are shared between different shops anyway? A database auto-increment number seems the most logical solution.

Comment: If it's that you need a unique value, then as @jeroen said, use Auto-Increment; have each script access the table (or a secondary table that defines the unique ID) and have them write a new entry, forcing the auto-increment and binding that number to the script's transaction.

Comment: having a UNIQUE constraint is another option

Comment: but how do i prevent, that the scripts read the same value before updating or auto-incemtenting the db ?

Comment: Another vote for AUTO_INCREMENT - easiest solution. But if you don't want to then you have to do a check before finalizing the order (and thus using the order number) to make sure it's unused. SELECT * from table where order_id='xxxxxxx' - in PHP test to see that the number of rows returned is 1.

Comment: could someone give me an example for the autoincrement solution

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: how autoincrement works is not the problem. But how can i prevent that two pgms read the same value ?